# How to add multiple markers to google maps?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geocoding

I used google maps with one marker for my rails app:

```js
<script>
  function initMap(lat, lng) {
    var myCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapOptions = {
    center: myCoords,
    zoom: 14
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCoords,
    map: map
});
}
</script>
```

```
<script>
    $('#map').prepend(initMap(<%= @location.latitude %>, <%= @location.longitude %>));
</script>
```

But how can I transfer multiple markers to the map?

I tried so, but it does not work:

```rb
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
   <script>
     $('#map').prepend(initMap(<%= location.latitude %>, <%= location.longitude %>));
   </script>
<% end %>
```

Then i create an array:

```rb
array = []
  @locations.each do |location|
  array.push([location.latitude, location.longitude])
  end
```

Which looks like this:

```rb
[[50.0874654, 14.4212535], [49.4447888, 32.0587805], [49.42105565, 32.1004058189433]]
```

And try pass to js:

```js
   <script>
     $('#map').prepend(initMap(<%= array %>));
   </script>
```

But it also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an overloading function initMap that takes in array like below:

```
<script>
  function initMap(lat, lng) {
    var myCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapOptions = {
    center: myCoords,
    zoom: 14
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCoords,
    map: map
});
}

function initMap(locationArr) {
      for (var i = 0; i < locationArr.length; i++) {
        var myCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(locationArr[i][0], locationArr[i][1]);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myCoords,
          zoom: 14
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myCoords,
          map: map
        });
      }

    }
</script>
```